# Postgres SQL query, that will group fields in associative array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, psycopg2

Example: I have table "tickets"

```
id, int
client_id, int
client_name, text
```

Instead of the usual select ("SELECT id, client_id, client_name FROM tickets") I need something that will give as result:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "client": {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "Mark"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to use SQL for this, there is [`json_build_object` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT
  json_build_object(
    'id', id,
    'client', json_build_object(
      'id', client_id,
      'name', client_name))
FROM
  tickets;
```

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import psycopg2
import json

conn = psycopg2.connect('')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
    with tickets(id, client_id, client_name) as (values(1,2,'x'),(3,4,'y'))
    SELECT
      json_build_object(
        'id', id,
        'client', json_build_object(
          'id', client_id,
          'name', client_name))
    FROM
      tickets;
    """)

for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row, json.dumps(row[0])
```

Output:

```
({u'client': {u'id': 2, u'name': u'x'}, u'id': 1},) {"client": {"id": 2, "name": "x"}, "id": 1}
({u'client': {u'id': 4, u'name': u'y'}, u'id': 3},) {"client": {"id": 4, "name": "y"}, "id": 3}
```

Comment: It works, but every result in "json_build_object". Looks like:
`{
"json_build_object": {id: ...}
},{
"json_build_object": {id: ...}
}`. Can I put data level up?

Comment: Without `"json_build_object"` key

Comment: @IldarAkhmetzyanov Probably we have some differences in code. Added example.

Comment: Problem with settings: cursor_factory=RealDictCursor.